# How to get Google Drive to show with queryIntentActivities()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-drive-api, android-package-managers

In our app we're trying to get files from other file storage apps. So for example, open our app, start app chooser, select dropbox, select file, opens file in our app.

I've set this intent to try and invoke other apps:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

The important part is `queryIntentActivities`, we're using the list of apps this returns to display what apps our users can choose. Apps like dropbox and Microsoft OneDrive show up no problem, but I Google Drive never shows up.

What do I need to set in my intent to have Google Drive be returned with `queryIntentActivities`?

Comment: any solution?, i am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android KitKat (API 19) and higher devices, apps can use the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) and build a [DocumentsProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html). In those cases, the system UI is providing the UI when you call `startActivity()` with an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` Intent - apps are not required to implement their own UI nor have an Activity that directly handles `GET_CONTENT`.

As the system UI provides access to both apps using the Storage Access Framework and legacy apps that only provide a `GET_CONTENT` Activity, you should **not** have your own app chooser and instead just directly execute the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` Intent and it'll work with all apps (and allow users to select files from multiple `DocumentsProvider`s rather than only from a single app if you have the [EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE) flag set).

Comment: I looked over Storage Access Framework and it seems like it should work with what we're doing, but I should clarify also that we're supporting API 14+ and we just need short term access to the document. It seems like `ACTION_GET_CONENT` is still what we should use for 14+. So then I guess my question is does Google Drive support `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`? All the answers i've seen say no but they're a few years old.

Comment: Yes, you should most definitely use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` if you just want temporary access to a file. You're just doing too much - `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` pulls up a UI that allows users to pick from *any* app that has an Activity that filters for `GET_CONTENT` **and** from any `DocumentsProvider`. Just launch the `Intent` you've built and you'll see them all listed. Keep in mind that due to the permissions required, only that system UI can read from `DocumentsProviders` so you'll never be able to build the same list within your app.

Comment: @ianhanniballake can you please share some code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Set data URI to intent and then check the queryIntentActivity.

Below code snippet, will also give Google Drive as ChooserIntent.

```
val packageManager = context.packageManager
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
        if (packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
            ).size > 0) {
            // PDF reader exists
            return true
        }
        // No PDF reader
        return false
}
```